# XML tag to add array in cache tag for layout file

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, ce-1.9.2.0, block-cache

As magento1.9.2 is added cachetags function in to `construct` functon i must have to give seperate cachetags for each block element because its get conflict with varnish to read key. i have solved this issue in.phtml file to set key like below

```
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block','',
         array(
         'cache_lifetime' => false,
         'cache_tags' => array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG."_twocmspages")
                          ))->setBlockId("twocmspages")->toHtml();
```

but if need to assign same `cache_tags` using xml with `setMethod` how can i do this.

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_id">
... set cachetag here
</block>
```

Is any one has idea how to add `cache_tag array` arrgument from XML ?

your help will be appreciated here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments in `<action>` can be defined as nested elements and will be converted to array:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_id">
    <action method="setTags">
        <tags>
            <tag1>cms_block_twocmspages</tag1>
            <tag2>( just in case you want to add more tags )</tag2>
        </tags>
    </action>
</block>
```

It should be noted that `<tag1>` and `<tag2>` will be the array keys, so you cannot use the same tag name and you cannot pass arrays with numeric indexes because XML tags cannot be numbers.

A more flexible solution is using JSON. Just specify which argument should be parsed as JSON with the `json` attribute of `<action>`:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_id">
    <action method="setTags" json="tags">
        <tags>["cms_block_twocmspages"]</tags>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: ha. it works with `json=...`? I never knew that. Can you tell me where this is parsed because I'm really curious.

Comment: Never mind. I found it: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L340. Good to know.

Comment: thanks for your answer, not working with json like this `<action method="setCacheTags" json="CacheTags">
        <cachetags>["cms_block_twocmspages"]</cachetags>
    </action>` will you please make me correct ? it's giving me fatal error :(

Comment: The elements are case sensitive, so if you use `<cachetags>`, it has to be `json="cachetags"`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can do it directly from the layout but you can do a trick.
Everything parameter you pass to an `<action>` tag can come from a helper.

Something like this:

```
<block type="something/here" name="some_name">
    <action method="setSomething">
        <something helper="module/getSomething" />
    </action>
</block>
```

This means that the method `setSomething` from the block `something/here` will be called and will receive as parameter the result of `Mage::helper('module')->getSomething()`.

So you can try the same for your code:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="block_id">
    <action method="setCacheTags">
         <tags helper="modulename/getBlockTags" />
    </action>
</block>
```

now just implement the method `getBlockTags()` in the helper `Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Data` that returns the array with your tags.

If you don't to add the method in a helper called `Data`, let's say you add it in the helper `Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Something` you need the `tags` tag like this:

```
<tags helper="modulename/something/getBlockTags" />
```

Comment: sir. Thank you very much to give quick reply. method still valid with custom code.+1 for me.